# List of List in realm Swift

Tags: swift, realm

I wanna to save a list of list in realm data base.
My model is

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class CompanyDetailRSM : Object{
    // properties and constructor
}
```

I wanna to create a list of list of above model type in below model

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class CompanyDetailRSMList: Object {

    // I wanna to declare a list in realm like
    // let list = [[CompanyDetailRSM]]() 
   var Two_D_list = List<<CompanyDetailRSM>>()// here I gets error

}
```

I am new to realm, so please help me to declare a 2 dimensional list in realm. Help will be appreciated

Comment: The List line should be *let Two_D_list = List<CompanyDetailRSM>()* but the bigger question is what is the purpose of *CompanyDetailRSMList* object?  If you want to create a list then you could store the *CompanyDetailRSM* in Realm and it would be a List. In other words, List generally is for relationships ( e.g. a Person object has several Dogs, a List ). Just asking so you don't go off in the wrong direction to start with.

Comment: @Jay. I have 3 list of type CompanyDetailRSM. I want to keep these lists in another list that is of type CompanyDetailRSMList with only 1 primary key for all 3 lists of CompanyDetailRSM. Thats the only reason. So I want to create a list like  " let list = [[CompanyDetailRSM]]()" in realm

Comment: It's not clear what the use case is; the design model you are proposing sounds complex and there is some confusion between the words *class* and *list*. e.g. *CompanyDetailRSMList* is not a list at all - it's a single class object. One of it's properties may be a *List* and that's a relationship to a set of *CompanyDetailRSM* class objects. It's also confusing as to (what is a) why there's a need for a '2 dimensional list' as with relationships, that may not be necessary. If it's set up correctly the relationship would make a single primary key accessible to all related objects.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a list of lists, you will have to declare an `Object` subclass that contains a single list property (representing the inner list), and then create a list of said `Object` wrappers (representing the outer list). Realm does not directly support multi-dimensional array types.